# Proguard not obfuscating in Android Studio

Tags: android, configuration, proguard, obfuscation, decompiling

I am trying to export signed apk, obfuscated with proguard. But after process, I can see my code and my class names in decompiler tool. Spent 1 day , but can't understand what I missed.

In my gradle file I specified :

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            apply plugin: 'maven'
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

proguard-rules.pro is empty.
Should I specify anything else to enable proguarding ? After decompilation

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `minifyEnabled` to `true` to enable proguard in your build configuration.

Comment: Thank you, that did the thing. One more question, why in every  documentation they have minifyEnabled false ?

Comment: I don't think so. Counterexample: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Running-ProGuard